# Insert html after certain amount of posts?

Tags: query, count

Is it possible after a certain amount of posts to close of a list and start a new one, like so...

Particularly after 6 posts...

```
<ul id="carousel">
<li>  
   <ul class="inner-items">

   <li>Post content</li>
   <li>Post content</li>
   <li>Post content</li>
   <li>Post content</li>
   <li>Post content</li>
   <li>Post content</li>

   </ul>

</li>
<li>  
   <ul class="inner-items">

   <li>Post content</li>
   <li>Post content</li>
   <li>Post content</li>
   <li>Post content</li>
   <li>Post content</li>
   <li>Post content</li>

   </ul>

</li>
</ul>
```

Something like this but obviously it needs to count he posts, if at all possible?

```
   <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'work','posts_per_page' => '-1' ) ); ?>


   <ul id="carousel">


   <li>  

          <ul class="inner-items">
          <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                 <li>
                 <?php the_content(); ?>        
                 <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'work-thumb' ); ?>
                 </li>

          <?php endwhile; ?>
          </ul>

   </li>


   </ul>
```

I'm not even sure if possible, but any help would be great thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following and it should do exactly what you want by checking the value of `$loop->current_post`.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'work','posts_per_page' => '-1' ) ); ?>
<ul id="carousel">
    <li>
        <ul class="inner-items">
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <?php if( $loop->current_post  && !($loop->current_post % 6)  ) : ?>
      </ul>
  </li>
  </li>
      <ul class="inner-items"> 
    <?php endif; ?>
            <li>
                <?php the_content(); ?>        
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'work-thumb' ); ?>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking.

But it doesn't seem to work :(

The first li has an ul with 2 li inside, it then closes and moves to another li with an ul and a single li which repeats.

Comment: answer edited; moved position and adjusted conditioanal code